# Change an image dpi without changing it's pixal format

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, resize, dpi

Every time I try to change the image's dpi, the pixel format (Color scheme - RGB, CMYK and such...) seems to change.
The only time I did succeed in saving the pixel format, the dpi, on debug mode, seems to change, but after the process is complete, it is changed back to it's original settings.

the code I tried is as followed:

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bmpInput = Image.FromFile(path) as Bitmap)
            {
                using (var bmpOutput = (Bitmap)bmpInput.Clone())                        
                {
                    foreach (var id in bmpInput.PropertyIdList)
                        bmpOutput.SetPropertyItem(bmpInput.GetPropertyItem(id));                        
                    if (doResize)
                        bmpOutput.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);

                    bmpOutput.Save(ms, bmpInput.RawFormat);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Try this before saving your Image in code.